# Tracking down non-GET AWS S3 requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and I'm having some trouble figuring out S3 requests usage. As far as I understand, the free tier limits are:

- 5 GB storage
- 20,000 GET requests
- 2,000 other HTTP requests

My free tier monitor says I'm at 1,723 "Global-Requests-Tier1" which I understand to be POST, PUT, COPY, LIST requests, and 2,315 "Global-Requests-Tier2", which seems to be GET requests.

But when I look at my only bucket's metrics, the latter number makes sense as I get about 60 GET requests/day and we're 42 days in... however, I have less than 30 other requests saved (and the bucket doesn't have many objects - 5).

I don't understand how to reconcile the metrics and the billing.

How should I go about tracking down these 'Tier1' requests that shouldn't exist, get billed but don't seem to appear anywhere ?

For extra context, this S3 is bucket holds a program's updates, it is primarily accessed through a CloudFront distribution, but it still publicly accessible for very early program versions, that look for the bucket rather than the distribution, to update. It should be accessed very rarely (in fact, 60 times per day is already suspicious), and I guess most importantly, nothing ever is expected to do any requests but GET (only the author - me - has write permissions anyway, and I use them exclusively manually, and I have most certainly not written 1700 times to it)

Does CloudFront make 'Tier1' requests ?

Comment: if it's publicly listable maybe it's being listed for a directory rendering, or it could be somebody pentesting known weak URLs that don't apply to you

Comment: **Side-note:** The cost is `$0.005 per 1000 requests`. It's probably not worth your time tracking-down every last request.